# Starting FGS with type none callerApp=ProcessRecord{c23a512 15473:mypackage/u0a350} targetSDK=34 has been prohibited

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-14

I'm getting this exception when scheduling a work manager task.

```
android.app.InvalidForegroundServiceTypeException: Starting FGS with type none callerApp=ProcessRecord{c23a512 15473:mypackage/u0a350} targetSDK=34 has been prohibited
```

I added

```
    <service
        android:name="androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService"
        android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync"
        android:exported="false"
        android:stopWithTask="false"
        tools:node="merge"/>
```

And the issue is still happening.

I then updated from work manager from `2.7.0` to `2.9.0` and still didn't help.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what the issue could be. The exception is happening at                                                                                                        `at androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService$Api31Impl.startForeground(SystemForegroundService.java:193)`

I've also checked and the merged manifest does have my stuff.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have missed a step. I had to add `ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_DATA_SYNC` to the `ForegroundInfo` constructor.